How to pass content to child including renderable parts in Angular?
I have two components: parent and child, with the following markup. It's vital to this example that the child fetches its own data to render and it must not be provided by the parent. As it's design now, it works as supposed to.
The parent.
<h1>I'm the papa</h1>
<app-lookup>
  <div>Some fixed content</div>
  <div>Some dynamic content (soon)</div>
</app-lookup>

The child.
<h1>I'm the sonny</h1>
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <span>{{item.value}}</span>
</div>
<div>Total: {{items.count}}</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>

At this stage, I realized that I don't know how to render something that's internal in the child as a part of the content passed from the parent. In the example above, the total is presented (when it's retried from a HTTP request subscribed to). But I'd like to control how it's presented by passing a template for it to the child.
Wish-for, pseudo-code (not working, naturally, since items doesn't exist in the parent) would be this.
<h1>I'm the papa</h1>
<app-lookup>
  <div>Some fixed content</div>
  <div>The cool total: {{items.count}}</div>
</app-lookup>

I can't use @Input/@Output because I want to encapsulate the data in the child. I've found a bunch of blogs on the child content and on data exchange. But I failed to find one that illustrates how to pass a template to be rendered with the child's fields. Naturally, the parent needs to guess the fields' names. I'm fine with that (and in case those aren't present, I'd just display nothing.

You can use a template reference variable (I called "data" to makes a look more comfortable)
<app-lookup #data>
  <div>Some fixed content</div>
  <!--see that you use data.any-property-of child -->
  <div>The cool total: {{data.items.count}}</div>
</app-lookup>

NOTE, really I don't like so much because you force know the properties of the child

I share your sentiment against the parent knowing the properties of the child. In my specific case, those will be very uniformed for any entity: id, name and value. But in a general case, it's a poor design, true. I'll take a look at the snippet you posted after lunch. Thanks, mate.

Okay, so I lied. I had to test it before the lunch break. And yes, it works like a charm. Now I only need to figure out how to deal with the content being inside *ngFor in the child and then, I'm ready for the weekend. +1 for the quickiness!

I've read something about needing to use *ngTemplateOutlet but I'm happy it wasn't so. Too much complexity for a simple thingy.

@KonradViltersten, the code really raises me a "a kind of ugly code" but while I try to find a better solution I think it can be useful
